# How to show second fragment from first fragment with in a single activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am developing a simple android app only for tablets and using android 4.0. My application have the main screen like as follow:

[image]

Oncreate() of Main Activity I am adding Fragment A in the main.xml using following code:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment imageFragment = new ImageFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, imageFragment);
ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

This fragment A just have only a Image view which is clickable. Now I want that when user click on Image view then another fragment (Fragment B) should call and it replace the image view. The Fragment B have a VideoView which play the video.

So My second screen should be like as follow:

[image]

My problem is I am not gettting "How to call second fragment from the first one with in main screen activity?"

I can use different activities but I do not want to do so and just want to run this using fragments.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the simplest way:

1) Inside `YourActivity`create a method:

```
public void goToSecondFragment(){}
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

2) In your first fragment, when you want to replace it, call:

```
YourActivity activity = (YourActivity) getActivity();
activity.goToSecondFragment();
```

Comment: Thanks rciovati. This is working fine for me and I am able to go to second fragment. But as I mentioned second fragment has VideoView and play the video but my video is not playing. It is showing dialog box with the message "Video can not be played". I am using following code-VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.main_video);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myvideo));
videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
videoView.start();
Please guide me.

Comment: Sorry,I have no experience with VideoView. I suggest you to ask another question, including also logcat output :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using below:

Adding a fragment with maintaining a back stack

```
FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
}
}); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.slate, fragment, "fragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And Replacing a fragment

```
FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.slate, fragment, "fragmentTag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Should work for you.